# How to use pipe to output id-address from a file and login?

Tags: linux

I have an ip-address stored in a file. I want to use a single-line command to output the ip-address from this file and then ssh log in this remote machine.
How can I get it with pipe.

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough to go on.  What have you tried?  What are your actual input data?  Do you use SSH keys or Kerberos or another passwordless authentication system, or do you need the password to somehow get in there too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a file that says

```
# cat test
192.168.32.205
```

then just do:

```
ssh root@$(cat test)
```